# My VM instance is missing from the console

Tags: google-compute-engine

I have a Linux VM on Google Compute Engine that I am accessing via SSH. It works just fine, but when I go to the Cloud Console, it asks me if I want to create a new VM as if I have none. I know I'm on the right account because it shows my billing balance has gone down.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fn1iM.png) Where did my server go?

Comment: Can you check the activity history in your web console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is weird. But it is important to make a differentiation that is not obvious once you start using Google Cloud Platform. The credentials you are using to access the Platform ( your email or a service account), the projects where an entity that any resource must be attached to and the billing account that is the payment profile that can have several projects associated.

In that case you could be in a different project, that is associated to the same billing account.

To check you can the project where your machine is, in the shell

```
Gcloud compute instances list
```

Here you will see the instances in your actual project. If nothing appears, reset gcloud configuration.

```
gcloud init
```

And change the project.

Comment: Found it! Thanks!